# Android Licensing Verification Library server response codes

Tags: android

To anyone who has implemented Android Licensing Verification Library

When you tested the following server response codes, did you get these two individual responses or did you get the NOT_LICENSED response code?
ERROR_CONTACTING_SERVER and ERROR_CONTACTING_FAILURE

It appears that I am not getting ERROR_CONTACTING_SERVER and ERROR_CONTACTING_FAILURE.

Please tell me about your experience testing these two codes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

May be you will get the response of ERROR_CONTACTING_SERVER possibly because of network availability problems. Once check the network availability. the following link will use full to you. http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html#test-env